# Why cant use the term highest popular but highest popularity

Tags: adjectives, superlatives

Most popular sport or highest popular ... why cant it be highest popular

Comment: Have you done any searches in dictionaries? Please edit your question to tell us what you found and why that still did not answer your question.

Comment: Because English doesn’t work that way. Do some basic research please!

Comment: [Please correct your question: Why **can't we or I or a speaker use** etc.]

Answer (score 3):

Because "highest" is an adjective and good to modify nouns, such as "popularity".

"Popular" is not a noun but an adjective and needs to be modified with an adverb. Just like you can't say "high popular", you can't say "highest popular" either.

That's why you say "*high* popularity" and "*highly* popular" and never the other way around.

You could say "most highly popular" if you really wanted. It would sound a little odd though.

Comment: Thank you very much ❤❤❤